# How to stop reading pipe() when '\0' is found

Tags: c++, linux

I am having trouble using read() and stopping the read(). Here is my code:

```
char buffer[15];
char value[15] = {'1'};
long m = 1;

write(pipeA[1], value, strlen(value) + 1);
close(pipeA[1]);
cerr << "The parent process is ready to proceed.\n";
cerr << "Parent: \t Value: " << value << endl;

 while(m > -999999999 && m < 999999999)
{

    while (read(pipeA[0], &buffer, 1) > 0)
    {
        cerr << "Test\n";

    }
    m += 200 - 3 * m;
}



close(pipeA[0]);
```

My question is how would i stop the read on buffer at the null character '\0'

Comment: `while (read(pipeA[0], &buffer, 1) > 0 && buffer[0] != '\0')`?

Comment: @scohe001 I have tried that but the loop never executes the test I have inside it. There should be at least 1 value in buffer since I wrote to it using the pipe so the while loop should execute at least once.

Comment: So is the issue that `buffer` has a null character? Or that the `read` is failing? If the latter, have you checked `errno`/`perror`?

Comment: @scohe001 yeah the issue is that the loop never executes the print statement I have to the console.

Comment: Sooooo have you checked `errno`/`perror` then? If you never execute the inner loop, that means `read` returned an error. Can you check and tell us what that error was?

Comment: @scohe001 how would i use perror in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html. So `perror("Some message");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I was closing my write pipe in main before executing this function.